# c# Regex.Split returns multiple instances of the same word

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

String: `WITH Date = {GETDATE()} AND Customer = 8824`

Pattern: `(([A-Za-z0-9@=><]+)|((\(([^)]+)\)))|(('[^,;]+'))|({[A-Za-z0-9@=><()]+}))+`

Output:

```
WITH
WITH

Date
Date

=
=

{GETDATE()}
{GETDATE()}

AND
AND

Customer
Customer

=
=

8824
8824
```

Obviously, the desired output is one instance of each word and not multiple.
I haven't included any flags.

Is there anything wrong with the pattern or should I include any flag?

Thanks.

Comment: Some of your alternatives use two bracket pairs, i.e. `((...))`, so you of course will get two identical capture groups for these.

Comment: @ckuri thanks, trying to fix it myself but if you can post a fixed regex as answer I'll give you some more internet gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why Regex?

https://regexr.com/3isdf  -->   `([{}()A-Za-z0-9@=><]+)`

If you include parentheses or curly-/square brackets inside `[]` as first characters, they are treated to be literally.

Simpler would be a string.Split(..) like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = 
            "WITH Date = {GETDATE()} AND Customer = 8824"
            .Split(" ".ToCharArray(),            // add other unwanted chars to splitter
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  

        foreach(var part in t)
            Console.WriteLine(part);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
WITH
Date
=
{GETDATE()}
AND
Customer
=
8824
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, your regex is perfect!  for your question, I use white space splitting now, but it becomes pain for parsing with certain strings so I can use some more flexible splitting (it is a small language similar to sql).

Comment: @Slimerecipe :) just beware of '' -they were present in your regex, but you did not provide any samples using ``''`` so I was unable to incoporate them. If you need them ignored, all should be fine.